# How to use @ControllerAdvice if there is no HTTP body?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, controller-advice

I'd like to have an `@ControllerAdvice` that is called for all HTTP requests on all controllers. Unfortunately it only triggers if there is a HTTP body in the request. If not, it's completely ignored. Isn't spring supposed to call `handleEmptyBody()` in this case?

**Edit**
All controllers are annotated with `@RestController`.

Any ideas?

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CatchAllRequestsAdvice implements RequestBodyAdvice {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CatchAllRequestsAdvice.class);

    @Override
    public boolean supports(
        MethodParameter methodParameter, Type targetType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType
    ) {
        LOGGER.info("");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public HttpInputMessage beforeBodyRead(
        HttpInputMessage inputMessage, MethodParameter parameter, Type targetType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType
    ) throws IOException {
        LOGGER.info("");
        return inputMessage;
    }

    @Override
    public Object afterBodyRead(
        Object body, HttpInputMessage inputMessage, MethodParameter parameter, Type targetType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType
    ) {
        LOGGER.info("");
        return body;
    }

    @Override
    public Object handleEmptyBody(
        Object body, HttpInputMessage inputMessage, MethodParameter parameter, Type targetType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType
    ) {
        LOGGER.info("");
        return body;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this advice?

Comment: Logging. And yes, I'm aware of the problems with the InputStream that can onyl be read once.

Comment: If you want to run before every request you are probably better of writing a filter or use one of the already exising request logging filters available in Spring (instead of rolling your own). Also your approach will only work for `@RestControllers` or `@RequestBody` annotated classes not for other requests (like regular `@Controller` without request-body).

Comment: M. Deinum is right, you could use a `OncePerRequestFilter`

Comment: All our controllers are annotated with `@RestController`. So the advice should be called for all requests on this controllers, right? But it isn't. It's only called if there's a request body.

Comment: In case the request body is empty, we can implement our custom logic into the `handleEmptyBody` method. We must return a value to use, either the provided object or an entirely new object.

Comment: Well, that's the probelm, `handleEmptyBody()` is never called if the request body is empty.

Comment: If you have decompiler, you can put a debugger at its invoke function and see what is stopping this. (RequestResponseBodyAdviceChain#handleEmptyBody)

Comment: Bala is right - whether the method will be called or not depends on several variables. I'd download source code of your Spring's dependencies and debug.